# Viewpager inside a fragment is blank when a listiview item in it is clicked and redirected to another fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am using a Viewpager inside a fragment and the viewpager is having a listview within its fragment.So when a list item is clicked it is redirected to another fragment in the same activity. So when i come back to my previous fragment(viewpager) the viewpager is blank! why is it so
I am desperate for the solution. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

```
//tabs inside the fragment
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
super(fm);
}

/* @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
// getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return 3;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
return "TAB " + (position + 1);
}*/
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

Fragment frag = null;
switch (position) {
case 0:
frag = new Full_Roaster_Fragment();
break;
case 1:
frag = new By_Sport_Fragment();
break;
case 2:
frag = new By_Team_Fragment();
break;
case 3:
frag = new Video_Critique_Fragment();
break;
}
return frag;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return 4;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
String title=" ";
switch (position){
case 0:
title="Full Roaster";
break;
case 1:
title="By Sport";
break;
case 2:
title="By Team";
break;
case 3:
title="For Video Critique";
break;
}

return title;
}
}
```

//Child Fragment of Viewpager

```
public class Full_Roaster_Fragment extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private View rootView;
public static ListView Analystslist;
public static FullRoasterAdapter full_Roaster_adapter;
public static ArrayList<ics.com.ics_app.Beans.AnalystSearchBean.Teams> analysts_search_arraylist1 = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,

ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_full_roaster, container, false);
initialization();

full_Roaster_adapter = new FullRoasterAdapter(getActivity(), ApplicationGlobalClass.analysts_search_arraylist);
full_Roaster_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Analystslist.setAdapter(full_Roaster_adapter);
return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
full_Roaster_adapter = new FullRoasterAdapter(getActivity(), ApplicationGlobalClass.analysts_search_arraylist);
full_Roaster_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Analystslist.setAdapter(full_Roaster_adapter);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Full Roaster on Activity Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

// Populates list with our static array
full_Roaster_adapter = new FullRoasterAdapter(getActivity(), ApplicationGlobalClass.analysts_search_arraylist);
full_Roaster_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
Analystslist.setAdapter(full_Roaster_adapter);
Log.e("sizeee",String.valueOf(ApplicationGlobalClass.analysts_search_arraylist.size()));
}

private void initialization() {

Analystslist = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.Analysts_listview);


Analystslist.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
// if (ApplicationGlobalClass.flag) {

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "full Roaster on Resume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
full_Roaster_adapter = new
..
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

ApplicationGlobalClass.user_id=ApplicationGlobalClass.analysts_search_arraylist.get(i).get(i).getId();
Log.e("userid",String.valueOf(ApplicationGlobalClass.user_id));
Log.e("userid2",String.valueOf(ApplicationGlobalClass.analysts_search_arraylist.get(i).get(i).getId()));
//here new fragment is calling from this fragment
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new FlexibleSpaceWithImageWithViewPagerTab2Activity()).addToBackStack("profile1").commit();

}
```

Comment: post your code....

Comment: Please recheck The Post

Comment: Where do you handle the going-back process? I can't find in the posted code, and it's the important part, since you have to restore the previous fragment, poping it form the backstack

Comment: //here new fragment is calling from this fragment
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new FlexibleSpaceWithImageWithViewPagerTab2Activity()).addToBackStack("profile1").commit(); So from here i move to fragment 2 and on its back press I again redirected to the fragment of viewpager.

Comment: I have'nt implemented any thing in the 2nd fragment for the goint-back process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onBackPressed()` in the activity that's hosting the fragments like this:

```
  public void onBackPressed() {
          int = count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            //additional code
        } else {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
```